# ListAdapter does not work

Tags: java, beacon, eddystone, kontakt.io

I have a mainActivity which has a button named monitoring. When I press the button it should show the nearby beacons. When I press the button an error shows up which say's my application stopped working. Here is the code of the button activity:

```
public class MonitoringBeacons extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProximityManagerContract proximityManager;

    ListAdapter beaconsAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    List<String> beaconsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring_beacons);
        KontaktSDK.initialize("kasjdhioasjkdoasdjo");

        proximityManager = new ProximityManager(this);
        proximityManager.setEddystoneListener(createEddystoneListener());

        setAdapter();


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String beacon = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        Toast.makeText(MonitoringBeacons.this, beacon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    protected void setAdapter() {
        if(beaconsList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MonitoringBeacons.this, "No beacons found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return ;
        }
        beaconsAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, beaconsList);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(beaconsAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        startScanning();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        proximityManager.stopScanning();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        proximityManager.disconnect();
        proximityManager = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startScanning() {
        proximityManager.connect(new OnServiceReadyListener() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                proximityManager.startScanning();
            }
        });
    }

    private EddystoneListener createEddystoneListener() {
        return new SimpleEddystoneListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEddystoneDiscovered(IEddystoneDevice eddystone, IEddystoneNamespace namespace) {
                beaconsList.add(eddystone.getUniqueId());
                setAdapter();
            }

            @Override
            public void onEddystoneLost(IEddystoneDevice eddystone, IEddystoneNamespace namespace) {
                beaconsList.remove(eddystone.getUniqueId());
                setAdapter();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

and the code of CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> beaconsList;
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<String> beaconsList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.beaconsList = beaconsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return beaconsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return beaconsList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);

        String singleBeaconItem = String.valueOf(getItem(position));
        TextView beaconText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.BeaconText);
        ImageView beaconImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.BeaconImage);

        beaconText.setText(singleBeaconItem);
        beaconImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.tough_beacon_1);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Ideally when I press the button the nearby beacons should be appeared as a list, and when a beacon is discovered or lost the list should automaticaly be updated.

**EDITED**

Stack trace in LogCat

--------- beginning of crash
08-06 17:02:15.276 2559-2559/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject, PID: 2559
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject.MonitoringBeacons}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject.MonitoringBeacons.onCreate(MonitoringBeacons.java:44)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-06 17:02:18.087 2559-2559/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2559 SIG: 9
08-06 17:02:22.298 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject-1/lib/x86
08-06 17:02:22.455 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject-1/lib/x86
08-06 17:02:22.604 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
08-06 17:02:22.715 3433-3460/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
                                                                                  [ 08-06 17:02:22.718  3433: 3433 D/         ]
                                                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa9a71c0, tid 3433
                                                                                     [ 08-06 17:02:22.754  3433: 3460 D/         ]
                                                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaa9a6920, tid 3460
08-06 17:02:22.768 3433-3460/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-06 17:02:24.070 3433-3460/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa9b17f0
08-06 17:02:26.685 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=397.5, y[0]=956.6797, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=70853, downTime=67680, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
08-06 17:02:26.685 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=397.5, y[0]=956.6797, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=70853, downTime=67680, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
08-06 17:02:26.686 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=397.5, y[0]=956.6797, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=70853, downTime=67680, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
08-06 17:02:26.686 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=397.5, y[0]=956.6797, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=70853, downTime=67680, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
08-06 17:02:28.817 3433-3460/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa9b17f0
08-06 17:02:29.373 3433-3460/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40938f0
08-06 17:02:29.375 3433-3460/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa1d53580 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa203f910
08-06 17:02:30.806 3433-3460/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4094e60
08-06 17:02:32.811 3433-3460/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb40938f0
08-06 17:02:35.874 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-06 17:02:35.874 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject, PID: 3433
                                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject.MonitoringBeacons}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setOnItemClickListener(android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                         at com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject.MonitoringBeacons.onCreate(MonitoringBeacons.java:44)
                                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
08-06 17:02:39.204 3433-3433/com.example.panagiotis.beaconsproject I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3433 SIG: 9

Any idea?

Comment: There should be a stack trace in LogCat when the app crashes.  Can you add this to your question?

Comment: @davidgyoung i added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace explains what is happening.

When this line of code executes:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(...
```

The `listView` has not yet been initialized, so it is null.  This causes a `NullPointerException`.

That variable is initialized in the `setAdapter()` method, but it may not be because the method exits early if `beaconsList.isEmpty()` evaluates to true.

The simple solution is to move the code that initializes `listView` to top of that method.